# Scala by name repeated parameter

Tags: scala, parameters

I want to do this, the parameter is lazy and repeatable:

```
def f(actions: (=> Try[String])*) = {
  actions.map{x =>
    if(x.isFailure) throw new Exception()
    ...
  }
}
```

So, I can evaluate parameter with this:

```
f(Try("a"), Try("b"), Try[String](new Exception()), Try({print("something"); "d"}))
```

The print("something") never be executed because parameters is lazy.

rather then:

```
def f(actions: (() => Try[String])*) = ???
f(() => Try("a"),() => Try("b"),() => Try[String](new Exception()), () => Try({print("something"); "d"}))
```

It just writing feeling boring.
Is Scala support the first one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap by name parameters as so:

```
implicit class ByNameWrapper[+A](a: => A) { def get: A = a }
```

And define your method as

```
def f(actions: ByNameWrapper[Try[String]]*) {
  ...
}
```

Usage is the same as normal by-name parameters:

```
f(Try { throw new Exception }, Try { println("a"); "b" })
```

Comment: Maybe the only one for currently solution.But I think it could be better if language support it.

Answer (score 1):

It's coming to dotty. Or it's already in dotty.

https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty/issues/499

Comment: That's the wrong kind of `=> A*`, I think. It's interpreted as `Function0[Seq[A]]` (using the parameter in the method evaluates *all* of the arguments at once). OP wants `Seq[Function0[A]]`, where each argument is separately evaluated.

Comment: Sorry for not support `(=> T)*`, it's just a `lazy val x: Seq[T]`. I need a `val x: Stream[T]` actually.